# git-tf tells on linux me “Could not lock” when checking in; how can I fix it?

Tags: linux, tfs, git-tf

I'm using git-tf to push to a TFS project on lin. Sometimes, when I try to check one or more commits into TFS, I get a message like this:

> Connecting to TFS... 
>   Checking in to $/MyProject: 0% git-tf: Could not
>   lock $/MyProject

What does this mean? What's keeping me from locking? And how can I fix this?

I found out that a workspace has locked the project, but I don't know which, and I don'w know how to recover this.

A search on internet hints me to all kind of Windows dependent fixes, but that does not help me on a linux system.

So, although this question appears to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090590/git-tf-tells-me-could-not-lock-when-checking-in-how-can-i-fix-it), it is more meant on how to fix the issue on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found out, that this can be fixed by removing the workspace that locked the repository.

```
tf workspaces -remove:myLockedWorkSpaceName
```

However, after that it was still locked remotely.
Eventually, I had to connect to the repository via visual studio from a windows machine.

There:

File->Source Control->Advanced->Workspaces

Toggle "remote workspaces"

Select the git-tf-##### workspace(s) and remove them.

After that, everything works again.

Somehow, I still don't know how to do this from a LINUX command line.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing need to be solved is finding out all locked files under `$/MyProject`, then unlock them.

There are several tools available on Windows platform, like `TFS Powertool` and `TFS SideKicks`, as you have read on other cases.

I can't find any existing tools on Linux to get all locked files, so [tfs command lines](https://github.com/konsumer/tfs) would be one solution. You can use **Status command** to list all checked out files under `$/MyProject`, the command should be similar to(I don't have a Linux system to test, you need to verify on your side):

```
tf status $/MyProject /user:* /recursive
```

Once you find out the checked out files, use **Lock command** `tf lock /lock:none` to unlock the files.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently the files were locked in a workspace that had been removed. For git-tf one can safely remove the workspace, as this does not harm functioning. The temporary workspaces are only initiated upon commit (and maybe pull). These workspaces are removed afterwards.